# how to sort and grouping a list by rtl alphabet in javascript

Tags: javascript, list, sorting, persian

I have list sample below :

```html
<ul>
<li class="cat-item"><span><b>● </b><a href="http://lilitext.rozblog.com/cat/6" >ابی<b>(19)</b></a></span></li>
<li class="cat-item"><span><b>● </b><a href="http://lilitext.rozblog.com/cat/7" >محسن<b>(19)</b></a></span></li>
<li class="cat-item"><span><b>● </b><a href="http://lilitext.rozblog.com/cat/8" >یگانه<b>(19)</b></a></span></li>
<li class="cat-item"><span><b>● </b><a href="http://lilitext.rozblog.com/cat/9" >داریوش<b>(19)</b></a></span></li>
<li class="cat-item"><span><b>● </b><a href="http://lilitext.rozblog.com/cat/10" >ساسی<b>(19)</b></a></span></li>
<li class="cat-item"><span><b>● </b><a href="http://lilitext.rozblog.com/cat/11" >علی<b>(19)</b></a></span></li>
<li class="cat-item"><span><b>● </b><a href="http://lilitext.rozblog.com/cat/12" >امید<b>(19)</b></a></span></li>
<li class="cat-item"><span><b>● </b><a href="http://lilitext.rozblog.com/cat/13" >حسام<b>(19)</b></a></span></li>
</ul>
```

How to sort and grouping a list by rtl alphabet in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

> The [String.prototype.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)  method returns a number indicating whether a
>   reference string comes before or after or is the same as the given
>   string in sort order.

It works for Persian words. You would create an ordered list of words using sample below and re-order DOM elements:

```js
var list = ['ابی', 'محسن', 'یگانه', 'داریوش', 'ساسی', 'علی', 'امید', 'حسام'];
var sortList = list.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b)
});
// sortList: ["ابی", "امید", "حسام", "داریوش", "ساسی", "علی", "محسن", "یگانه"]
```